# How do i read a byte array as a multi dimensional array in C#?

Tags: c#, python, sockets, unity-game-engine, textures

I am trying to use Python to send images to Unity C# where I want to display the images overlayed on the current display (for every frame).
I am currently using zmq to receive a byte array of a PNG image from python into Unity. 
The image is in the form of a numpy array of shape 256x256x4. Using the function `np.tobytes`, the length of the message is 2097152 which is larger than (256x256x4)

Once the message is sent to Unity, I am attempting to get a colour array from the byte array to use `Texture2D.readPixels32()` using the following code snippet.

```
var colorArray = new Color32[message.Length/4];
for(var i = 0; i < message.Length; i+=4)
{
    var color = new Color32(message[i + 0], message[i + 1], message[i + 2], message[i + 3]);
    colorArray[i/4] = color;
}
Texture2D tex2new=new Texture2D(Screen.width,Screen.height);
print (Screen.height + " " + Screen.width + " " + colorArray.Length);
tex2new.SetPixels32(colorArray);
```

The error is `SetPixels32` called with invalid number of pixels in the array
`UnityEngine.Texture2D:SetPixels32(Color32[])`
How do I read the byte array into a texture?
Is there a better way to display the byte array once the game is played in Unity in real-time?

Comment: how do you read the png image in python? and could you show the result of print

Comment: If you want to convert a 1d into a 2darray- cant test this right now but ive made similar things like this:
    
    // to get the index of and x and y coord
    int index = x + (y * w);  or y + (x * w)  // 

    // to get the x and y of an index
    int x = index % w;
    int y = Round((index / w) - 1);  // im no sure about this right now !?

where w is the x and y length of the 2d array. That works if the 2darray has the same x and y length.

Im not sure if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(Screen.width/2, Screen.height,TextureFormat.RGBA32,false);
byte[] message = null;
bool gotMessage = false;
while (true)
{
    gotMessage = client.TryReceiveFrameBytes(out message); // this returns true if it's successful
    if (gotMessage) break;
}


tex.LoadImage(message);
byte[] mesg1 = tex.EncodeToPNG();
dest = cam2.targetTexture;
Graphics.Blit(tex, dest);
RenderTexture.active = dest;
```